# wso2 5.3.0 authenticate using one secondary user store and authorize using another

Tags: authentication, wso2, authorization, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I'm new to wso2 and there are many new concepts to me ... I'm looking for a yes/no answer to the following question:

With wso2is, is it possible to authenticate users using one secondary user store (AD / LDAP) and authorize them using another secondary user store (JDBC, a database with only user and role tables)?

If the answer to the question is "yes", can you please provide me some links to some related examples or documents?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. we can use different user stores.

Please refer

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Architecture

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Single+Sign-On

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! it is possible. Write your own custom UserStore and overwrite the method getting claims from user store.

Google it and you will find steps to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll write a custom user store. @ Agam